# Different connections for same environment in database.properties

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

i need access to several databases per environment.
Until now i've only seen examples with exactly one database connection config per environment in database.properties.
Is it possible to have several connection configs in there for an environment and let ActiveJdbc handle opening the correct one when using DB.open("first") or do i need to load these configs by myself in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have named connections and bind them to your thread:

```
new DB("corporation").open("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "p@ssw0rd");
new DB("university").open("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "activejdbc", "activejdbc");
```

After that, you can declare models to associate with named connections:

```
@DbName("corporation")
public class Employee extends Model {}
...
@DbName("university")
public class Student  extends Model {}
```

For more, see the doc for your case: 
http://javalite.io/database_connection_management#multiple-database-example

Comment: Ok that's what i'm finally using now. I've written my own connection pool manager (which handles the different DataSource instances from the configuration file).

Comment: you might wan  to see this then: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/test/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/C3P0PoolTest.java